# how to change the group of rahul from L1M1 to L1M2

Tags: java

```
import java.util.;

public class Student {

    String Name;
    String Group;
    String Phonenumber;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        Student student = new Student("Ayush", "L1N1", "9876543210");
        arrayList.add(student);
        Student student2 = new Student("Rahul", "L1M1", "9876543211");
        Student student3 = new Student("Gaurav", "L1N2", "9876543212");
        arrayList.add(student2);
        arrayList.add(student3);
        System.out.println("Name" + "Group" + "Phonenumber");
        for (Student all : arrayList) {
            System.out.println(all.Name + " " + all.Group + " " + all.Phonenumber);
        }
    }

    public Student(String Name, String Group, String Phonenumber) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Group = Group;
        this.Phonenumber = Phonenumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow naming convention lowerCamelCase for attributes/variables/parameters : `name, group, phoneNumber`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
student2.Group = "L1M2";
```

or

```
arrayList.get(1).Group = "L1M2";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you an entire new data-structure. Maybe a Map, if this is something, that happens verry frequently.

With your current data-structur, as TpoM6oH pointed out, you can simply get(1) and it will return the wanted Student.

But for that to work correctly, you would have to introduce a generic, since other wise, you deal with Objects and would have to cast the Object to a Student.

```
ArrayList<Student> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Mor Informations about generics can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

For a little bit cleaner code, i would further recommend changing the `ArrayList<Student>` to the interface `List<Student>`

If you however do not know the order they apear in, you could iterate over the List and compare the names like this:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Student student : list) {
    if(student.Name.equals("Rahul")) {
        student.Group = "L1M2";
    }
}
```

In Java 8, you also have the Option to use Streams, which are a nice addition. With a Stream, this line would look like this:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(student -> student.Name.equals("Rahul"))
    .forEach(student -> student.Group = "L1M2");
```

which would change the Group of all Rahuls in your list.

Note, that your code as potential other Problems, like Concurrency problems (because you use atributes instead of getter/setter methods), but i am not going unto those, since it was not part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8 and + :

```
 arrayList.stream().map(student -> {
      if(student.getName.equals("Rahul")){
         student.setGroup("L1M2");
        }
    return student;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());;
```